# express-validator not producing validation errors

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am facing issues while trying express-validator v4.3.0.
There is one basic example of login with post request. There are two parameters email and password. Below is my code.

**routes.js file:**

```
var express = require('express');  
var router  = express.Router();  
var validator = require('./validator');

router.post('/login', [sanitize('email').trim(), 
 validator.publicRouteValidate('login')], (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
}
```

**validator.js file:**

```
'use strict';  
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');  
const { matchedData, sanitize } = require('express-validator/filter');

module.exports = {  
  publicRouteValidate: function (method) {  
    return (req, res, next) => {  
      switch (method) {  
        case 'login':  
          check('email').isEmail().withMessage('email must be an email')  
            .isLength({min: 109}).withMessage('minimum length should be 100 characters')  
        break;  
      }  

      var errors = validationResult(req)
      console.log(errors.mapped())
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
         res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array()[0].msg })
      } else {
         res.send('login')
      }
}}}
```

Now when I am doing POST request with only email and value of email is abc. So I should get the error like **email must be an email**. But I did not get any response. So What is the issue I do not know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `publicRouteValidate` function is only creating a validator, but it is never being called.

This happens because, as documented, `check` returns an express middleware. Such middleware must be given to an express route in order for it to do its work.

I recommend you to break that function in two: one that creates your validators, and another that checks the request for validation errors, returning earlier before touching your route.

```
router.post(
    '/login',
    createValidationFor('login'),
    checkValidationResult,
    (req, res, next) => {
        res.json({ allGood: true });
    }
);

function createValidationFor(route) {
    switch (route) {
        case 'login':
            return [
                check('email').isEmail().withMessage('must be an email'),
                check('password').not().isEmpty().withMessage('some message')
            ];

        default:
            return [];
    }
}

function checkValidationResult(req, res, next) {
    const result = validationResult(req);
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        return next();
    }

    res.status(422).json({ errors: result.array() });
}
```

Comment: If i want to validate request params that pass through only body or only query then how we can implement in latest express validator version.

Comment: If you want both at the same, then have a look at [`buildCheckFunction`](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#buildcheckfunctionlocations). Otherwise you can use either `body()` or `query()`.

Comment: If I want to access request in createValidationFor() then how we can do that?

Comment: Use a [custom validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#customvalidator).

Comment: But I want something like. If **req.body.type** exist then apply validation for type field. If **req.body.type** = 'email' then apply validation for email, if **req.body.type** = 'password' then apply validation for password. Now How I will get this in **_createValidationFor()_** function.

Comment: Your question asked for something different. If this is the case I recommend you to ask another one, so that this one is kept for future reference.

Comment: @gustavohenke Would it be possible for createValidationFor(route) function to have access to the request object? I would need to determine the validations based on a value inside the request body. Thanks!

Comment: @BalázsVincze Only if you make it a middleware, then do something like [this](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/485). Otherwise, keep track of [this issue](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/439)

Comment: @gustavohenke Thanks. The middleware solution works, but what if I want to call multiple checks (i.e. an array) after each other? Is it possible to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BalázsVincze Yes, the example is in that issue I linked before.

Comment: @gustavohenke Oh I missed that, sorry. I found another way to call multiple checks which might be a bit more intuitive, I posted a comment on the issue.